# serialize doesn't work with select2 library

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm calling `$('form').serialize()` when sending my data to the server but my select2 selected value is not being sent. Eventhough I initialize select2 on my `#my_field` the value of this input is always blank even after I selected an entry from the select box.

```
<input id="my_field" name="my_field" />
```

---

```
// initialize select 2
$('#my_field').select2()

// my attempt
$('#my_field').on "select2-selecting", (e) ->
  selectedVal = $('#s2id_'+e.target.id).find('.select2-chosen').html()
  $( this ).val(selectedVal)
```

I tried one thing that seemed like it should work but it's not! What I was trying to do here is observe the change event on select 2 and when it changes manually update the value of `#my_field with` the selected value. I tested and it properly triggers and when I debug it also updates the input value but after this event executes, the value is back to blank so I'm assuming something is reseting it.

What's the correct way to set the value of my input field to the value that was selected?

**edit problem reproduced here**
http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/16/

- start typing 'fe' and select an entry from the list
- look at the html, the original input tag does not have the value set on it

Comment: Thanks for the note but I can't find this that's why I'm looking at alternatives, what is it called?

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: Select2 automatically updates the value of the original input. You don't need to do it manually. You can verify this by watching the element in a document inspector.

Comment: It doesn't, look at this example, start typing 'fe' then select an entry from the list, if you see the <input in the source, a value is never set on it and that's the problem I'm having. http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/16/

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="16155" data-init-text="Bla bla" name="input" id="test" style="width:300px;" tabindex="-1" title="" class="select2-offscreen">`

Comment: That's exactly the demo I tested on before my first comment above. Works for me. :-)

Comment: ahhh! I can't beleive this, it was this fragile that if I didn't have a value tag preset on my input then it didn't work. It seems to work now thanks! One last thing though it's showing the ID, any idea on how make it use a different field?

Comment: `value` is an attribute or property, not a tag. :-) I'm not sure what you're asking about the ID.

Answer (score 0):

If when you send the data to be processed (php, asp, java) and only receive a single value even if you selected multiple values, you need to add [] at end of the name of the "select", because if you not include these, the input only pass one value, and if you include [] at end of the name, all selected values will be passed, example:

```
<select id="comboData" name="comboData[]" class="select2" multiple="multiple"></select>

$('#comboData').select2()
```